# Python Beginner - Number Guessing Game print issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I'm having an issue simply with print("Out of Guesses!\nYou Lose, Try Again!"). Whenever, the player runs out of guesses it prints out all print print statements twice here's the output:

```
Too Low!  
Out of Guesses!  
You Lose, Try Again!  
Too Low!
```

When it should just print:

```
Out of Guesses!
You Lose, Try Again!
```

Code:

```
import random

number = random.randint(0,20)
player = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 5
out_guesses = False

while player != number and not out_guesses:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        player = int(input("Input Your Guess: "))
        guess_count += 1

    else:
        out_guesses = True
        print("Out of Guesses!\nYou Lose, Try Again!")

    if player == number:
        print("You Win!")
    if player < number:
        print("Too Low!")
    if player > number:
        print("Too High!")
```

Comment: Because you don't stop the program... It keeps checking the guess. You should `break` after the `Out of guesses` print

Comment: you need to use `elif` and `else` instead of two `if`(s) in the last.

Comment: Alternatively, move the `guess_count` check to be **after** the actual guess check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `out_guesses` scenario :

```
  if player == number:
        print("You Win!")
    if player < number:
        print("Too Low!")
    if player > number:
        print("Too High!")
```

This code block is getting executed twice instead of one. You've to stop it by logic. Here is a sample :

```
import random

number = random.randint(0, 20)
player = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 5

while player != number:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        player = int(input("Input Your Guess: "))
        guess_count += 1
        if player == number:
            print("You Win!")
        if player < number:
            print("Too Low!")
        if player > number:
            print("Too High!")
    else:
        print("Out of Guesses!\nYou Lose, Try Again!")
        break
```